# $.post function is not returning the correct data

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, post

I'm using $.post to deliver data to my main page from droppable elements. Yet when I echo out the the data I'm getting my toolbar echoed out to me as well as the data I fetched.

```
if (isset($_POST['data'])){
$data = $_POST['data'];
echo $data;
```

The javascript containing the $.post is below

```
if(dropbox && dropbox1 !== ''){
        $.post("account_main.php", 
          {data: $(this).text()}, 
          function(data) {
                $('#demo').html(data);
          });       
        }
```

And a visual for the script using the droppable elements is [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Kxtvg/247/), but the problem is not shown here, can't duplicate it. I am open to any suggestions.

Comment: "I'm getting my toolbar echoed out to me"... what? a toolbar?

Comment: Always exit() your PHP after you make ajax responde. 
it will remove any further informations. 
! plus please set to your jquery.POST your data type.. etc "HTML" at the end between }), ....    },"HTML");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (isset($_POST['data'])) {
    echo $_POST['data'];
    # Other stuff
    exit; # Kill the script
}
```

If I understand your problem correctly, that should sort it :)

Comment: Still getting the same results, could it be something else?

Comment: The condition and `exit` should be ABOVE anything of the HTML is output.

Answer (score 0):

Just try :

```
if (dropbox && dropbox1 !== "") {
    var url, params, callback;
    url = "account_main.php";

    params = {
       "data": $(this).text()
    };

    callback = function(data) {
         $("#demo").html(data);
    }

    $.post(url, params, callback, "html");
}
```

Please note that I would strongly advise you to use JSON for your response instead of HTML.

```
header("Content-type: application/json");
echo json_encode($my_result);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
data: $(this).text()
```

$(this) refers to the $.post, I think that's not the data you want.

Comment: I'm afraid you're wrong here. For example, it could be placed inside a click event, in which case the $(this) would refer to that.